# Tailwind in next.js dark: variant inside tsx file and scss module's is not working but working in global.scss

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I'm using next-themes library for dark mode, it is appending and detecting Dark mode in body tag I'm getting the dark mode class light and dark below mentiond html

```
<html class="dark" style="color-scheme: dark;">
```

and it is also working when I'm using inline style dark: it is detecting dark: mode

```
<a href="#home" class="dark:text-white nav-link">Register / Login</a>
```

My components files are inside src/components/layout/header/Header.tsx

inside global.module.scss dark: is working but not inner scss module

For example global.scss

```
@layer base{
  body{
    @apply dark:bg-[#292929]
  }
}


a.nav-link{
    @apply dark:text-white text-[#242424];
}
```

above code is working
but inner module scss is not working

Header.module.scss

```
.line {
    @apply dark:bg-white bg-[#242424];
}
```

Comment: How are you using the `.line` class name in your code?

Comment: in next.js I'm importing the styles and using string Interpolation  like className={styles.line}